# Typescript interface for tree structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, tree

I want to define an interface for tree structure.

Each node can have zero or more children:

```js
export interface TreeNode {
  children?: Array<TreeNode>;
}
```

I have implemented a traversing function for `TreeNode`s.

```js
export function traverseTree(treeData: Array<TreeNode> | TreeNode, callback: (treeNode: any) => any) {
  // implementation omitted
}
```

I want to test it. Code is as follows:

```js
const treeData = [
  {
    name: "root_1",
    children: [
      {
        name: "child_1",
        children: [
          {
            name: "grandchild_1"
          },
          {
            name: "grandchild_2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "root_2",
    children: []
  }
];
const traversingHistory = [];
const callback = (treeNode: any) => {
  traversingHistory.push(treeNode.name);
}
traverseTree(treeData, callback);
```

However, compilation fails because `treeData`'s argument of type cannot be applied to `traverseTree`.

I don't want to add attribute `name` to interface `TreeNode` because a tree node can have dynamic properties. How can I modify `TreeNode` interface to accept more general types?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error you are probably getting is:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type

If you want to allow other keys, it's got to be part of the type. You can do this with an index signature:

```
export interface TreeNode {
  [key: string]: any // type for unknown keys.
  children?: TreeNode[] // type for a known property.
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I guess that using a `generic` instead `[key: string]: any` fits better:

```
export type Tree<T> = T & {
  children?: T[];
}
```

keeping the required and optional fields of the `Item` type we want to build a tree: `Tree<Item>`
for this question, the Item is: `{ name: string }`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this union type with `object`:

```
type TreeNode = {
    children?: Array<TreeNode>;
} & object;
```

Comment: Answer of Alex Wayne is better. But as a variant